# Calling reddit api to get access token is being blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, api, oauth, cors, reddit

I am trying to use reddit api in my react application. But when I try to get access token I get the following error.
[image: Access to manifest at 'https://www.redditstatic.com/desktop2x/img/favicon/manifest.json' from origin 'https://www.reddit.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.]

```
    const response = await axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token",
      auth: {
        user: process.env.REACT_APP_REDDIT_CLIENT_ID,
        password: process.env.REACT_APP_REDDIT_CLIENT_SECRET,
      },
      data: {
        grant_type: "authorization_code",
        code: code,
        redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/login",
      },
    });
```

I am new to Reddit Api and Oauth so I can't really understand what's the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. The issue was that parameters sent cannot be in json format.
SO I had to change them to url encoded.

```
 const params = new URLSearchParams();
      params.append("grant_type", "refresh_token");
      params.append("refresh_token", refreshToken);

      const config = {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
        auth: {
          username: process.env.REACT_APP_REDDIT_CLIENT_ID,
          password: process.env.REACT_APP_REDDIT_CLIENT_SECRET,
        },
      };

      const response = await axios.post(getPrefix(url), params, config);
```

Also due to my local environment being http. It was causing cors issue. So I prefixed my url with [cors-anywhere](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/corsdemo) and it works. I tried using `reddit.local` as mentioned but it doesn't seem to work.